# Google Cloud Platform Creating Firewall Rule What Allows Request Coming From One And Only Specific Country

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

i am kind of new on GCP. I am trying to figure out how can i create a firewall rule that allows requests coming from one specific country like Belgium, Italy etc. I may miss the tips in docs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [Using firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) section [Creating firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#console). Unfortunately, GCP Firewall doesn't provide geo filtration at the moment.

Please check if [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/) suits your use case. If so, you'll be able to use geography-based access controls to allow or deny traffic based on source geo using Google’s geoIP mapping.

If your use case requires geo filtration provided by GCP Firewall you can file a [feature quest](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).